# function declared inside document.ready is undefined?

Tags: jquery, function, jqgrid, scope

If I declare a function inside document.ready, I get an error. 
Like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function updateSizeOptions()
    {
        alert("updateSizeOptions");
    }

    var jGrid = $("#list_main");
    jGrid.jqGrid({
        url:'db.php?ajaxOp=getData',
            colModel:[
                $.extend(true,
                { name:'shape_id'
                  ,index:'shape_id'
                  ,edittype:'select'
                  ,formatter:'select'
                  ,editoptions: { onclick:"javascript:updateSizeOptions();" }
                }
                ,{}
            ]
        ....
});
```

It will give Error : "ReferenceError: updateSizeOptions is not defined". 
But If I moved the function outside document.ready, everything works fine. 
Like this

```
function updateSizeOptions()
{
    console.debug("updateSizeOptions");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var jGrid = $("#list_main");
....
```

WHY ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because in Javascript, functions declared within other functions are *local* references, and are not visible outside the scope of their parent function. If you want to make your `updateSizeOptions` function globally accessible, you will need to assign a reference to it in a global namespace, say a `window` property:

```
window.updateSizeOptions = updateSizeOptions;
```

Comment: Ahh.. I got it. Because jqgrid plugin can't find the function in the global scope when making the grid. Oh man.. It cost me a day !
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined the function `updateSizeOptions` inside the anonymous function passed to `$(document).ready`, `updateSizeOptions` will only be available inside that anonymous function unless you export it. (i.e. `window.updateSizeOptions = updateSizeOptions`)

Functions (or/and variables) defined in the global scope is literally defined *under* the `window` object, so if you define the function in the global scope and you do `alert(window.updateSizeOptions)` you will see it shows a function. `window.updateSizeOptions == updateSizeOptions` will return `true`.

However if you define it inside a local scope, you will see `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Scope. When you put something inside `$(document).ready`, the code will only be excecuted when this event is triggered and the things like variables and functions declared inside the event do not exist outside of the event unless set globally.

When you do `javascript:updateSizeOptions();` it will look for a function in the global scope that in this case does not exist, therefor `undefined`.